# In the restful API, how to authenticate both public and secret keys using PHP?

Tags: php, rest

I am working on my restful API. I have seen different APIs that are required a Public key while requiring to send a Secret key in the request. I know that it's another security layer but, I am confused about the authentication logic. Is the below script is fine or the logic will be different?

```
// Let say defined in database:
$stored_public = 'YWRtaW4tMTIz';
$stored_secret = 'cHVibGljX2tleQ';

// Coming from API request:
$requester_public = 'some_key';
$requester_secret = 'some_key';

if ( $stored_public == $requester_public && $stored_secret == $requester_secret )
{
    // Success response
}
else
{
    // Unauthorized
}
```

**Another question** is why the header() function with authorization argument if the keys can send through the POST/GET request?

Please guide me. I shall be very thankful to you.

Thanks